# Why is Amazon Redshift serializing my concurrent updates?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I have a table on Amazon Redshift with ~600 million rows. I have a python process that issues the following query over a sqlalchemy_redshift connection:

```
begin;
UPDATE dogs
SET computed_dog_type = f_get_dog_type(name, breed, age, color)
WHERE week = :week;
commit;
```

That query works fine; however, it is too slow to run over 600 million rows at once. The where clause effectively limits by week where a week's worth of rows range from 2K to 2-3 million.

I wrapped the query code in python threads where the execution looks like this:

```
16:38 $ python dog_classifier.py update_range 2009-10-05 2009-10-26
11-02 16:39 PTC          INFO     DOG CLASSIFIER STARTED
11-02 16:39 PTC          INFO     START update of dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-05
11-02 16:39 PTC          INFO     START update of dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-12
11-02 16:39 PTC          INFO     START update of dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-19
11-02 16:39 PTC          INFO     START update of dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-26
11-02 16:45 PTC          INFO     END update of 338378 records in dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-12 in 6 minutes
11-02 16:52 PTC          INFO     END update of 355796 records in dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-05 in 13 minutes
11-02 16:59 PTC          INFO     END update of 337909 records in dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-19 in 20 minutes
11-02 17:07 PTC          INFO     END update of 281617 records in dogs.computed_dog_type for week: 2009-10-26 in 28 minutes
11-02 17:07 PTC          INFO     DOG CLASSIFIER STOPPED AFTER UPDATING 1313700 RECORDS
```

where I'm running a month at a time - typically, 4-5 weeks of data being about a million rows or so.

It appears as though the queries are being serialized on redshift. If you examine the output from cloud watch dashboard while these queries are running, the peaks and valleys are very clearly tied to my update queries where there is essentially one week peak per query per run.

[image: cloudwatch dashboard]

I have considered that the default query queue is a likely culprit but examining its behavior at runtime seems challenging.

How can I debug this? What would be causing the queries to serialize like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that your **User-Defined Function** (UDF) is slowing-down processing. The [UDF Constraint documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-constraints.html) says:

> The number of UDFs that can run concurrently per cluster is limited to **one-fourth of the total concurrency level for the cluster**. For example, if the cluster is configured with a concurrency of 15, a maximum of three UDFs can run concurrently. After the limit is reached, UDFs are **queued for execution** within workload management queues.

Also, if your UDF uses an [`IMMUTABLE` return type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html), then Redshift can cache the UDF return values, which can help speed operations.

You could potentially avoid running the UDF by **creating a lookup-table** with all values and joining against that table, which allows Redshift to optimize the query. Such a table should be set to `DISTKEY ALL` to distribute the table across all nodes.